# Pandas json_normalize to flatten a dictionary with values as columns

Tags: python, pandas, normalize

Here's  a sample of the data I'm trying to flatten:

```
location = [{'id': 225,
  'country': 'US',
  'country_code': 'US',
  'country_population': 327167434,
  'province': '',
  'last_updated': '2020-05-06T11:33:46.184263Z',
  'coordinates': {'latitude': '37.0902', 'longitude': '-95.7129'},
  'latest': {'confirmed': 1204351, 'deaths': 71064, 'recovered': 0},
  'timelines': {'confirmed': {
                  'latest': 1204351,
                  'timeline': {
                     '2020-01-22T00:00:00Z': 1,
                     '2020-01-23T00:00:00Z': 1,
                     '2020-01-24T00:00:00Z': 2}
                    },
                'deaths': {
                  'latest': 71064,
                  'timeline': {
                     '2020-01-22T00:00:00Z': 0,
                     '2020-01-23T00:00:00Z': 0,
                     '2020-01-24T00:00:00Z': 0}
                     }
                    }
                    }]
```

I'm unable to get the timeline for confirmed & deaths in a usable format. I either get a column for each date with this:

```
pd.json_normalize(
    data = location,
    record_path=['timelines','confirmed','timeline'])
```

Or a row with date and no value for the count:

```
pd.json_normalize(data = location[0]['timelines']['confirmed'])
```

Desired output is something like:

[image]

Thanks in advance; any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: `confirmed.timeline` and `deaths.timeline` always have the same `len`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm interested in wrangling/reshaping with Pandas and wanted to try a solution via that method.  It didn't make sense to duplicate the latest value with each timeline date row so I broke the data into 2 frames: latest & timeline.  Still fairly new to this so any feedback/potential improvements are appreciated.

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data = location, sep = '_')

#list of current state / non-timeline columns
latest_cols = ['id', 'country', 'country_code', 'country_population', 'province', 'last_updated',
              'coordinates_latitude', 'coordinates_longitude', 'latest_confirmed', 'latest_deaths',
              'latest_recovered', 'timelines_confirmed_latest', 'timelines_deaths_latest',
              'timelines_recovered_latest']
covid_latest = df[latest_cols]

# remove id & country from latest cols for inclusion w/ timeline
latest_cols = latest_cols[2:]
covid_timelines = df.drop(columns = latest_cols)

# reshape from wide to long
covid_timelines = pd.melt(
    frame = covid_timelines,
    id_vars = ['id', 'country'],
    var_name = 'status_date',
    value_name = 'case_count')

# split the timelines value and keep columns with date and type
timeline_cols = covid_timelines.status_date.str.split('_', expand=True)
timeline_cols.columns = ['timelines', 'case_type', 'timeline', 'str_date']
timeline_cols = timeline_cols.drop(columns = ['timelines', 'timeline'])


#add split cols back to covid_timelines
covid_timelines = pd.concat([covid_timelines, timeline_cols], axis=1)

# string to date and drop the dup date column
covid_timelines.status_date = pd.to_datetime(timeline_cols.str_date).dt.date      
covid_timelines = covid_timelines.drop(columns = 'str_date')

#pivot death & confirmed from rows to cols
covid_timelines.pivot_table(
    index = ['id', 'country', 'status_date'],
    columns = 'case_type',
    values = 'case_count' )
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

taking it a step further with @Trenton Mckinney's data, we can do all the processing outside of pandas, and bring the finished product into a dataframe :

Step 1 : create a function to process the data :

```
def extract_data(location,keyword):
    collection = []
    for ent in location:
        #get the timeline data for either 'confirmed' or 'deaths'
        #determined by the keyword
        b = ent.get('timelines').get(keyword).get('timeline')
        #switch out from dicts to a list of key value pairs
        items = list(b.items())
        #for each value in the items list, 
        #append the country and population
        for val in items:
            val = val + (ent.get('country'), ent.get('country_population'))
            #collect each result into a collection list
            collection.append(val)
    #create a dataframe
    cols = ['date', 'count', 'country', 'country_population']
    res = pd.DataFrame(collection, columns = cols)
    res = res.set_index(['country','country_population'])
    #conditionals depending on the keyword
    if keyword == "confirmed":
        res = res.add_prefix('confirmed.timeline.')
    elif keyword == "deaths":
        res = res.add_prefix('deaths.timeline.')
    return res
```

Step 2 : Apply function per keyword - 'confirmed' or 'deaths'

```
confirmed = extract_data(location,'confirmed')
deaths = extract_data(location,'deaths')
```

Step 3 : [concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the dataframes, on the columns axis :

```
pd.concat([confirmed,deaths],axis=1)



                         confirmed.timeline.date    confirmed.timeline.count    deaths.timeline.date    deaths.timeline.count
country country_population              
US      327167434       2020-01-22T00:00:00Z                1     2020-01-22T00:00:00Z                             0
        327167434       2020-01-23T00:00:00Z                1     2020-01-23T00:00:00Z                             0
        327167434       2020-01-24T00:00:00Z                2     2020-01-24T00:00:00Z                             0
AF      327167435       2020-02-22T00:00:00Z                2    2020-02-22T00:00:00Z                              1 
        327167435       2020-02-23T00:00:00Z                2    2020-02-23T00:00:00Z                              1
        327167435       2020-02-24T00:00:00Z                3    2020-02-24T00:00:00Z                              1
AS      327167436       2020-03-22T00:00:00Z                3    2020-03-22T00:00:00Z                              2
        327167436       2020-03-23T00:00:00Z                3    2020-03-23T00:00:00Z                              2
        327167436       2020-03-24T00:00:00Z                4    2020-03-24T00:00:00Z                              2
```

**UPDATE** : love the feedback from @DanilaGanchar and decided to rewrite the code. All the computation occurs outside Pandas till the final moment : speed reduction as well : 853us

```
d = []
for entry in location:
    #pull dictionary for country and population
    country_population = {'country':entry.get('country'), 
                        'country_population':entry.get('country_population')}
    #pull data for the confirmed and death timelines
    confirmed_timeline = entry.get('timelines').get('confirmed').get('timeline').items()
    death_timeline = entry.get('timelines').get('deaths').get('timeline').items()
    #set keys for the deaths and confirmed dicts
    deaths = ('deaths.timeline.date', 'deaths.timeline.count')
    confirmed = ('confirmed.timeline.date', 'confirmed.timeline.count')
    #attach keys to the values in deaths and confirmed
    #this will become the column names in the dataframe
    confirmz = (dict(zip(confirmed,conf)) for conf in confirmed_timeline)
    deathz = (dict(zip(deaths,death)) for death in death_timeline)
    #aggregate the data into one dict
    #and lump the dicts into one list
    for content, cont in zip(confirmz, deathz):
        content.update(country_population)
        content.update(cont)
        d.append(content)

pd.DataFrame(d)




   confirmed.timeline.date  confirmed.timeline.count    country country_population  deaths.timeline.date    deaths.timeline.count
0   2020-01-22T00:00:00Z                   1             US  327167434  2020-01-22T00:00:00Z    0
1   2020-01-23T00:00:00Z                   1             US  327167434  2020-01-23T00:00:00Z    0
2   2020-01-24T00:00:00Z                   2             US  327167434  2020-01-24T00:00:00Z    0
3   2020-02-22T00:00:00Z                   2             AF  327167435  2020-02-22T00:00:00Z    1
4   2020-02-23T00:00:00Z                   2             AF  327167435  2020-02-23T00:00:00Z    1
5   2020-02-24T00:00:00Z                   3             AF  327167435  2020-02-24T00:00:00Z    1
6   2020-03-22T00:00:00Z                   3             AS  327167436  2020-03-22T00:00:00Z    2
7   2020-03-23T00:00:00Z                   3             AS  327167436  2020-03-23T00:00:00Z    2
8   2020-03-24T00:00:00Z                   4             AS  327167436  2020-03-24T00:00:00Z    2
```

Comment: That's a very clean process and easy to follow.   Thanks!

Comment: @user1169290 `set_index` + `concat` + 2 `iterations` + 2 `df` is very clean and easy? ok... ))))

Comment: It's definitely faster than my solution.  I created a dataset with 99999 records `x = [y for y in location for _ in range(33333)]`; this answer took 746 ms, while mine took 38.6 s.  Well done, good job.!  I'll give 10 rep for this answer. @DanilaGanchar your took 3.06s with the expanded dataset.  Good job too!

Comment: Thanks @TrentonMcKinney! I checked ur profile and u have quite a lot of certs under ur belt. more power to ur elbow mate

Comment: Thanks.  I'm just like to learn...sadly, `pandas` isn't always the answer.

Comment: @sammywemmy I don’t understand why the author changed the “approved answer” several times. I'll give rep for you.

Comment: Didn’t even check to see y. Frankly SO allows us get beta at coding; points r a bonus. Thanks for d rep tho :)

Answer (score 1):

- See inline comments
- Must use pandas v0.25 or greater
- Within each record `confirmed.timeline.date` & `deaths.timeline.date` must be the same length.

```py
import pandas as pd

# create a dataframe
top = pd.DataFrame(location)

# dataframe of desired columns
d = top[['country', 'country_population', 'timelines']].copy()

# transform timelines
d[['confirmed.timeline.date', 'confirmed.timeline.count']] = d.timelines.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([list(x['confirmed']['timeline'].keys()), list(x['confirmed']['timeline'].values())]))
d[['deaths.timeline.date', 'deaths.timeline.count']] = d.timelines.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([list(x['deaths']['timeline'].keys()), list(x['deaths']['timeline'].values())]))
d.drop(columns=['timelines'], inplace=True)
d

# explode the lists created in the last step and then join the data
cols = ['confirmed.timeline.date', 'confirmed.timeline.count', 'deaths.timeline.date', 'deaths.timeline.count']
d = d[['country', 'country_population']].join(pd.concat([d.explode(col)[col] for col in cols], axis=1))

print(d)

  country  country_population confirmed.timeline.date confirmed.timeline.count  deaths.timeline.date deaths.timeline.count
0      US           327167434    2020-01-22T00:00:00Z                        1  2020-01-22T00:00:00Z                     0
0      US           327167434    2020-01-23T00:00:00Z                        1  2020-01-23T00:00:00Z                     0
0      US           327167434    2020-01-24T00:00:00Z                        2  2020-01-24T00:00:00Z                     0
1      AF           327167435    2020-02-22T00:00:00Z                        2  2020-02-22T00:00:00Z                     1
1      AF           327167435    2020-02-23T00:00:00Z                        2  2020-02-23T00:00:00Z                     1
1      AF           327167435    2020-02-24T00:00:00Z                        3  2020-02-24T00:00:00Z                     1
2      AS           327167436    2020-03-22T00:00:00Z                        3  2020-03-22T00:00:00Z                     2
2      AS           327167436    2020-03-23T00:00:00Z                        3  2020-03-23T00:00:00Z                     2
2      AS           327167436    2020-03-24T00:00:00Z                        4  2020-03-24T00:00:00Z                     2
```

### Test Data

```py
location = 
[{'coordinates': {'latitude': '37.0902', 'longitude': '-95.7129'},
  'country': 'US',
  'country_code': 'US',
  'country_population': 327167434,
  'id': 225,
  'last_updated': '2020-05-06T11:33:46.184263Z',
  'latest': {'confirmed': 1204351, 'deaths': 71064, 'recovered': 0},
  'province': '',
  'timelines': {'confirmed': {'latest': 1204351,
                              'timeline': {'2020-01-22T00:00:00Z': 1,
                                           '2020-01-23T00:00:00Z': 1,
                                           '2020-01-24T00:00:00Z': 2}},
                'deaths': {'latest': 71064,
                           'timeline': {'2020-01-22T00:00:00Z': 0,
                                        '2020-01-23T00:00:00Z': 0,
                                        '2020-01-24T00:00:00Z': 0}}}},
 {'coordinates': {'latitude': '37.0902', 'longitude': '-95.7129'},
  'country': 'AF',
  'country_code': 'AF',
  'country_population': 327167435,
  'id': 226,
  'last_updated': '2020-05-06T11:33:46.184263Z',
  'latest': {'confirmed': 1204351, 'deaths': 71064, 'recovered': 0},
  'province': '',
  'timelines': {'confirmed': {'latest': 1204351,
                              'timeline': {'2020-02-22T00:00:00Z': 2,
                                           '2020-02-23T00:00:00Z': 2,
                                           '2020-02-24T00:00:00Z': 3}},
                'deaths': {'latest': 71064,
                           'timeline': {'2020-02-22T00:00:00Z': 1,
                                        '2020-02-23T00:00:00Z': 1,
                                        '2020-02-24T00:00:00Z': 1}}}},
 {'coordinates': {'latitude': '37.0902', 'longitude': '-95.7129'},
  'country': 'AS',
  'country_code': 'AS',
  'country_population': 327167436,
  'id': 227,
  'last_updated': '2020-05-06T11:33:46.184263Z',
  'latest': {'confirmed': 1204351, 'deaths': 71064, 'recovered': 0},
  'province': '',
  'timelines': {'confirmed': {'latest': 1204351,
                              'timeline': {'2020-03-22T00:00:00Z': 3,
                                           '2020-03-23T00:00:00Z': 3,
                                           '2020-03-24T00:00:00Z': 4}},
                'deaths': {'latest': 71064,
                           'timeline': {'2020-03-22T00:00:00Z': 2,
                                        '2020-03-23T00:00:00Z': 2,
                                        '2020-03-24T00:00:00Z': 2}}}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I look at the approved answer. 2 `df`, 2 `apply()`, 1 `copy()`, 1 `drop()`, 1 `concat()`, 1 `join()`. But you can do it using only `json_normalize`. The main problem in `timeline` structure. Is a `dict`, but not `list` of `dicts`. So all what you need is convert `timeline` to:

```
[{
   'confirmed_dt': '2020-01-22T00:00:00Z',
   'confirmed_count': 0,
   'deaths_dt': '2020-01-22T00:00:00Z',
   'deaths_count': 0,
}, ...]
```

Just an example:

```
def format_timelines(data: list):
    for rec in data:
        new_timelines = []
        confirmed = rec['timelines']['confirmed']['timeline']
        deaths = rec['timelines']['deaths']['timeline']
        for (k, v), (k2, v2) in zip(confirmed.items(), deaths.items()):
            # just set any keys(column names)
            new_timelines.append({
                'confirmed_dt': k,
                'deaths_dt': k2,
                'confirmed_count': v,
                'deaths_count': v2,
            })

        rec['new_timelines'] = new_timelines
    return data


df = json_normalize(
    format_timelines(location),
    ['new_timelines'],
    meta=['country', 'country_population']
)
```

I think it's easier. Hope this helps.